# Indentations in Docstring

Tags: python, python-3.x, docstring

I am using Python 3.9.12 on Spyder 5.2.1.

I am trying to write a docstring as follows.

```
def readArray(parameters, key):
    """
    NAME
        readArray - Read an array from an input file specified by the key in the parameters field
    SYNOPSIS
        readArray(parameters, key)
    ARGUMENTS
        parameters - dictionary of input parameters
        key        - key to array of interest
    """
```

However, when I hover over the function name, the indents are ignored.  I have tried doing the indents with both spaces and tabs.  Neither work.

Is there a way to have indentations in docstrings?

Comment: The Python docstring (`readArray.__doc__`) has indentation. The problem is probably how Spyder displays docstrings

Comment: Which IDE are you using? That may have an impact on the hover behaviour.